# How do I increase the nfsd threads on boot?

Tags: boot, server, 22.04, nfs

using: Linux nfs-naw 5.15.0-86-generic #96-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 20 08:23:49 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I am running a nfs server on this machine.  I have edited the file /etc/defaults/nfs-kernal-server

```
cat << EOF > /etc/default/nfs-kernel-server
RPCNFSDCOUNT=30
RPCNFSDPRIORITY=0
RPCMOUNTDOPTS="--manage-gids --debug all --no-nfs-version 3"
NEED_SVCGSSD="no"
EOF
```

When I look at the init.d/nfs-kernal-server I see this in the script

```
# Read config
DEFAULTFILE=/etc/default/nfs-kernel-server
RPCNFSDCOUNT=8
RPCNFSDPRIORITY=0
RPCMOUNTDOPTS=
NEED_SVCGSSD=no
RPCSVCGSSDOPTS=
PROCNFSD_MOUNTPOINT=/proc/fs/nfsd
if [ -f $DEFAULTFILE ]; then
    . $DEFAULTFILE
fi
```

When I boot the machine I still only get 8 threads running.  The only way I can spool this up is with the command  `echo '32' > /proc/fs/nfsd/threads`

I tried editing the init.d/nfs-kernal-server directly and still only get 8.  What am I missing?

Thanks
Brad

Answer (score 2):

Adding it to the `[nfsd]` section of the `/etc/nfs.conf` file should fix it.

```
[nfsd]
threads=32
```

Then restart the service

```
sudo systemctl restart nfs-server.service
```

Comment: thank you that worked perfectly.